# Darsain / Sly - infinite loop - the first slide should apear at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, sly-scroller

I have used Darsain/Sly ([Github](https://github.com/darsain/sly)) to build a product slider. It works really nice but there is no functionality to make an infinite loop. On Github, I found the same reported issue.

Did anyone use this library and know how to add simple slides loop?

My idea is to use methods next(), prev(), add(), remove() from [here](https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/docs/Methods.md) and create own functions to do that.

Or maybe you can recommend any other similar library to achieve results as [here](https://www.gucci.com/uk/en_gb/pr/men/mens-ready-to-wear/mens-outerwear-leather-jackets/leather-biker-jacket-with-appliqus-p-474078XG4521082?position=11&listName=ProductGridComponent&categoryPath=Men/Mens-Ready-To-Wear/Mens-Outerwear-Leather-Jackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played with the library a little more and I have found pretty much good trick to make an infinite loop. It's not a perfect solution for now, but can be a good base for someone who wants to use it.

Please see below code:

```
var slider  = $('#smart'),
    slide = slider.children('ul').eq(0),
    wrap   = slider.parent(),
    options = {
        itemNav: 'basic',
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        scrollBy: 1,
        pagesBar: wrap.find('.pages'),
        activatePageOn: 'click',
        speed: 1000,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,
        cycleBy: 'items'
    };

var sly = new Sly(slider, options);

sly.on('change', function(eventName){
    var clone = $(slide).find('li').first().html();
    $(slide).append('<li>'+ clone + '</li>');
    $(slide).find('li').first().remove();
    this.slideTo(1);
});

sly.init();
```